# Why is this snippet invalid TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, code-snippets, transpiler

Consider the following TypeScript snippet:

```ts
function containsWord(): boolean {
    const fullText: string[] = ['This is a sentence with seven words'];
    const word: string = 'word';

    return (
        fullText.reduce((acc, sentence) => acc && sentence.includes(word), true)
    );
}

console.log(containsWord())
```

When trying to compile this snippet in VS Code or in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBUCGMwGcDqcBOAJgBQCUAXIgEZxwA2ApmkgN4BQinyCWUiodOgBUGADyiVe+TAHMA2gF1EAXkRyA5EIAWMLIl2I0iLAzBRTEBogDuMKFuMMAbqZsFCWdQoDcHLimw+a3dJKGkwGRVEdWCidV8-TnwGKBB8JGJErk4BYTEoADpkwhBLYmI0CAgAGkczCwZSFQA+QyrEADIOuvNIBgLMCDoQQgYsYljCUlqwkEas0l8AXzY2AKx6fro4GWIA9ExcdzJSIA), I get the following error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Which I don't really understand. What's really surprising is that moving the content of the return statement to a variable fixes the issue:

```js
function containsWord(): boolean {
    const fullText: string[] = ['This is a sentence with seven words'];
    const word: string = 'word';

    const result = fullText.reduce((acc, sentence) => acc && sentence.includes(word), true);

    return result;
}

console.log(containsWord());
```

Or explicitly setting the callback arguments types:

```js
function containsWord(): boolean {
    const fullText: string[] = ['This is a sentence with seven words'];
    const word: string = 'word';

    return (
        fullText.reduce((acc: boolean, sentence: string) => acc && sentence.includes(word), true)
    );
}

console.log(containsWord());
```

I'm very confused by the fact that the first snippet is invalid while the two others are fine according to TypeScript. It looks like type inference is somehow failing in the first snippet. Shouldn't they all be equivalent?

Comment: An addition: if we explicitly state the type of initial value (`true as boolean`) - the error also goes away. Looks like the `true` is somehow inferred to be `string` (which it obviously isn't).

Comment: `fullText.reduce<boolean>(...)` works too. Seems like TypeScript chooses the wrong overload.

Comment: Even just extracting the `.reduce()` call lets TS compile correctly: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBUCGMwGcDqcBOAJgBQCUAXIgEZxwA2ApmkgN4BQinyCWUiodOgBUGADyiVe+TAHMA2gF1EAXkRyA5EIAWMLIl2I0iLAzBRTEBogDuMKFuMMAbqZsFCWdQoDcHLimw+a3dJKGkwGRVEdWCidV8ubkDEUSiBYTEoADp8BkIQS2JiNAgIABpHMwsGUhUAPkNSxAAyZsrzSAYszAg6EEIGLGJYwlIKsJAahK5cqBB8JFFfAF82NgCsei66OBliAPRMXHcyUiA). Weirdly, if it's placed at the `return` it infers the generic argument as `.reduce<string>()`

Comment: Wow, this is strange! Looks like contextual typing is somehow messing things up, but I don't know why.  Maybe someone's reported this as a GitHub issue (and if not, maybe someone should).  I'll look into it.

Comment: Ah, it's https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46707 which is considered a design limitation.  The failure cascade looks like: compiler knows the return type needs to be `boolean`; the `true` input is contextually typed by `boolean` which causes it to be inferred as literal `true` instead of `boolean`. But the callback doesn't return only `true`, so the call is seen as invalid. And everything explodes after that.  Do you want me to write up an answer explaining this in detail? You're just looking for the reason and not workarounds (which you already have), right?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your answer! Yes I'm definitely interested in the details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS4.7+

This was a design limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#46707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46707) for details. It was fixed for TypeScript 4.7 by [microsoft/TypeScript#48380](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48380).

---

### PREVIOUS ANSWER FOR TS4.6-

This is a design limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#46707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46707) for details. It's sort of a cascading failure that results in some weird errors.

This is a design limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#46707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46707) for details. It's sort of a cascading failure that results in some weird errors.

---

A generally useful feature was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29478](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29478) allowing the compiler to use the expected return type of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) to propagate a contextual type back to the generic function's arguments.  That might not make much sense, but it sort of looks like this:

```
function foo<T>(x: [T]): T { return x[0] }

const bar = foo(["x"]);
// function foo<string>(x: [string]): string

const baz: "x" | "y" = foo(["x"]);
// function foo<"x">(x: ["x"]): "x"
```

Note how the type of `bar` is `string`, since the call to `foo(["x"])` infers the type parameter `T` as just `string`.  But `baz` has been [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) to be of type `"x" | "y"`, and this gives the compiler some context that we want the `T` type in the call to `foo(["x"])` to be narrower than `string`, so it infers it as the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"x"`.

This behavior has a lot of positive effects in TypeScript, and a few problems.  You ran into one of the problems.

---

The [TypeScript typings for `Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0043abe982aae0d35f8df59f9715be6ada758ff7/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1379-L1386) look like this:

```
interface Array<T> {
  reduce(cb: (prev: T, curr: T, idx: number, arr: T[]) => T): T;
  reduce(cb: (prev: T, curr: T, idx: number, arr: T[]) => T, init: T): T;
  reduce<U>(cb: (prev: U, curr: T, idx: number, arr: T[]) => U, init: U): U;
}
```

That's an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) method, with multiple call signatures.  The first one is not relevant, since it doesn't have an `init` parameter.  The second one is non-generic, and expects the accumulator to be of the same type as the array elements.  The third one is generic and lets you specify a different type, `U`, for the accumulator.

The one you want here is that third, generic call signature.  Let's imagine that's the one the compiler chooses. In your call to `reduce()`, the compiler expects the return type to be `boolean`.  Therefore the generic type parameter `U` has a `boolean` context, and that contextual type propagates back to the `init` parameter as per ms/TS#29478. The compiler looks at the `init` parameter being `true` and infers it to be the literal `true` type instead of `boolean`.

Which is the first problem, because your callback returns `acc && sentence.includes(word)`, which is `boolean` and not necessarily `true`:

```
let b: boolean = fullText.reduce(
    (acc, sentence) => acc && sentence.includes(word), // error!
    // --------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // boolean is not assignable to true
    true
);
/* (method) Array<string>.reduce<true>(
     cb: (prev: true, curr: string, idx: number, arr: string[]) => true, 
     init: true
   ): true */
```

This is the error you would see if `reduce()` only had the one call signature.  And maybe from this it would be at least vaguely intuitive to employ a the workaround of writing `true as boolean` for `init`, or manually specifying `U` to be `boolean` like `fullText.reduce<boolean>(...)`.

But unfortunately other stuff is going on which makes the error less obvious.

---

The compiler doesn't only try the generic call signature; it also tries the non-generic one, where `init` is expected to be the same type as the array elements.  This one also failed, and this time for good reason, since it would mean that `init` would have to be a `string`, and that the callback returns a `string`, and that `reduce()` returns a `string`, which is wrong in a bunch of ways:

```
b = fullText.reduce( // error!
// <-- string is not assignable to boolean
    (acc, sentence) => acc && sentence.includes(word), // error!
    // --------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // boolean is not assignable to string
    true);

/* (method) Array<string>.reduce(
    cb: (prev: string, curr: string, idx: number, arr: string[]) => string, 
    init: string
  ): string */
```

The compiler tries both overloaded call signatures and they both fail.  If you look carefully at the error messages, the compiler is complaining about both of them:

```
/* No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(cb: (prev: string, curr: string, idx: number, array: string[]) => string, 
    init: string): string', gave the following error.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(cb: (prev: true, curr: string, idx: number, array: string[]) => true, 
    init: true): true', gave the following error.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'. */
```

Generally speaking when all overloads fail, the compiler picks the earliest one to use.  And that unfortunately means that the call signature that returns `string` is what the compiler decides happens. So the `return` statement is, apparently, returning a `string` in your `containsWord()` function which is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) to return a `boolean`.  And *that's* what causes the error that's confusing you:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Bizarre!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gLABQyVyA5hCAEoQAmArkjgKoEAUCARgC5kPAA5QIAN2GcANMgSsMwvPODMAHsJCsAtv2jy4y5HgDaAXQCUyALxE5yUMDAyrMgNwVqyEAHsQAHF6JjYkPiERcSkVeUUTVSdNbT0DKCMEyxt7UzUQFxV3Uy9yAF8KdEwsADpxPzB6rFEIarpGFnYUWzQMbFqoesbm6okwiBLKvrqGsCaW-yCQjqQ7Hqr+wdnh0c6SihhWEAQwYACFALA4UABnAHU-KGYeIv4-PwAbCDgQEm9qBAC1zAyAO73eeAgGlcyCBUFANEsqzMAHI8AALYDXJxYuAw+iQI4oADuLjReMk9GQRIezGuyIse0o-0BwOpj2EsPhq2RbOYyMZPk+wMirw+Xx+3VB4MhYFaSzGPD+PioPEQCHk13x9CQ2SIauQADIDXjwNqWqAEO9WMwINceLyrPIAPRO5DQAZQACESuVLuQAFpA0Hg8GiAA-CORqPRmOxiM+nx+0Wfb7Y3z1ZBwa7XYA0EBwfifZANYtQVgQBPUMBlitMqhWEqJgBUIl0EDAaL8zBsk1wnJANAI1UgQNCnRw1fLvEr-0iYgk0lL5biSigHOr8LUyV8qUMmZM-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-ciZ5wzwKMAOwAGwAJw2E+FDlIF5AAiA1xitUjU0HwFxXAb9yPM8VhBfshzHKcPwvX4+C8FZZh4NYKgkMgIVhcgGhmAADBYyA6xQ+tAsg-DGO+bw8GYABEGhJ9YJR+gcRwnGcLs4Ie7vCGYh7e+TQVR8KcAAF7CCnSfIAAPsgSdYPXkoJ8nqfpxQmcOznztvDgdeF8gndp0UddBUAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear answer! There is still one thing that I don't understand. How come we don't get the same issue when assigning the value to a variable before returning it? In that case, it succeeds at inferring a boolean type and not a true type.

Comment: I showed above that it does happen if the variable is annotated as `boolean`. If you assign it to an unannotated variable or you don’t annotate the return type of the function then the problem goes away (and it’s inferred as `boolean`, ironically).  It’s the external context that messes things up.

Comment: It's now fixed in the latest TypeScript versions!

Comment: @RobinDosAnjos Good catch.  Looks like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48380 fixed it for TS4.7.  Edited answer.